# Does Mongoose cache models?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Although I'm updating a schema, Mongoose keeps sending an earlier version of it to MongoDB.

(Adding a new field does not show).

The issue occurs only for a particular collection. Updating other collections is fine.

What would be the possible explanations ?

Could Mongo have cached the model when compiled for the first time ?

Comment: After you update the Schema Model, be sure to put down the server and run it again. If you don't do that, old Schema Model will be applied.

Comment: The backend I work on was built with serverless. What would be the alternative process ?